# IP Filtering in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008

I want to filter some IPs in sql server.  I read on some blog that suggested using a trigger.  How can I do this?  I don't use a firewall or isc or other things.

Comment: I want to use a hammer to play this guitar.  Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

- [LOGON TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx)
- Extract IP address from client_net_address in [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx)
- reject connections in the trigger based in IP address

I haven't done it myself, but it should be straightforward to do

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..i want use this article  http://sql-articles.com/articles/security/ip-address-blocking-or-restriction-in-sql-server but SQL Server response a error on this line : "FOR LOGON" .. and i can't fix it.. can you help me ?